# .png Images will not display on webpage

Tags: 12.04, server, png

I am having an issue where my '.png' images will not display in my webpage.  I am running 12.04 server.  The images are linked and called right in the code.  The server recognizes that the files are there, aka not 404 error.  Is there a special library I need for '.png' pictures?

Comment: Did you try with different browsers?

Comment: @rishiag Tried with Google Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.  No luck.  The '.jpg' images load that have the same file location as the '.png'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation I was transferring the files via WinSCP as text based.  Found out that '.png' files need to be transferred via binary.